Can I use Stack-Navigation in Modal?
I want to put Stacks into Modal by react-native.
I tried to put stack navigator in Modal, but I can't press pressable element such as TouchableOpacity or Pressable and etc...
ps. If there's no way to put stacks into Modal, let me know how to make full screen modal in react-navigation.

I came across a similar question on GitHub and found this solution by @leggomuhgreggo:
Tree
app
| -- modal-stack
|    |-- _layout.tsx
|    |-- modal-screen-1.tsx
|    |-- modal-screen-2.tsx
| -- _layout.tsx
| -- index.tsx

app/modal-stack/_layout.tsx
// app/modal-stack/_layout.tsx
import { Stack } from 'expo-router/stack';

export const unstable_settings = {
  // Ensure that reloading on `/modal` keeps a back button present.
  initialRouteName: 'modal-screen-1',
};


export default function Layout() {
  return (
    <Stack>
      <Stack.Screen name="modal-screen-1" />
      <Stack.Screen name="modal-screen-2" />
    </Stack>
  );
}

app/_layout.tsx
// app/_layout.tsx

import { Stack } from 'expo-router';

export {
  // Catch any errors thrown by the Layout component.
  ErrorBoundary,
} from 'expo-router';

export default function  RootLayoutNav() {
  return (
      <Stack>
        <Stack.Screen name="index" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="modal-stack" options={{ headerShown: false, presentation: 'modal' }}/>
      </Stack>
  );
}

Source: Expo router issue #512
